# PHP PDO With Large Tables

Tags: php, pdo

I find myself creating tables with many columns frequently. I would like to have a faster way to prepare queries in PHP using PDO. The below code works properly and as expected, but I'm not sure if it is the appropriate way to achieve this task. Please advise.

```
//Define table name. Hardcoded and does not rely on user input.
$TableName = "...";

//Define table fields. These are all hardcoded into the PHP code and does not rely on any user input.
$Fields = array("Field 1", "Field 2", ... , "Field 20");

//Establish PDO connection
$conn = new PDO("...");

//Automatically prepare statement INSERT query.
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO " .$TableName." (".implode(',',$Fields).") VALUES (:". implode(',:',$Fields) .");");

//Automatically bind post variables and sanitize using a self-defined function.
foreach ($Fields as $Value):
    $stmt->bindValue(':'.$Value, sanitizeString($_POST[$Value]));
endforeach;

//Execute Query
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: In PDO, queries are _prepared_ only once and sent to MySQL. So it is optimized and isn't the bottleneck. Also, you might want to look into bulk insert rather than insertion row by row.

Comment: Its as appropriate as it could be given the way you are loosely defining the table columns. I prefer a more rigid approach so that looking at the code, you know exactly what table and what fields are being manipulated... but thats purely objective and opinion based; as most times, I only want to 'sanitize' specific fields, not every single one of them on the same rules. Like for example, I never alter a password field, but I always `trim` a user's first name etc.

Answer (score 0):

For creating tables and filling them with data I would suggest database migration manager.

Something like https://phinx.org/

1. its database agnostic - meaning its supports MySQL,PostgreSQL,SQLite,Microsoft SQL Server.
2. you can simply migrate this to new project
3. its easier to manage in teams

Now based on your example and taken from documentation https://book.cakephp.org/phinx

a) Create table - https://book.cakephp.org/phinx/0/en/migrations.html

simple in command line `vendor/bin/phinx create MyNewMigration`

```
use Phinx\Migration\AbstractMigration;

class MyNewMigration extends AbstractMigration
{
    public function up()
    {
        $table = $this->table('followers', ['id' => 'user_id']);
        $table->addColumn('follower_id', 'integer')
              ->addColumn('created', 'timestamp', ['default' => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'])
              ->create();
    }
}
```

b) fill with data - https://book.cakephp.org/phinx/0/en/seeding.html

`php vendor/bin/phinx seed:create UserSeeder`

```
use Phinx\Seed\AbstractSeed;

    class PostsSeeder extends AbstractSeed
    {
        public function run()
        {
            $data = [
                [
                    'body'    => 'foo',
                    'created' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                ],[
                    'body'    => 'bar',
                    'created' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                ]
            ];
    
            $posts = $this->table('posts');
            $posts->insert($data)
                  ->saveData();
        }
    }
```